# arm-linux-gcc:undefined reference to error

Tags: linux, gcc, bootloader, armv7, tms570

I would like to compile the cortex-r4's bootloader on linux with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc,the makefile gives me an undefined reference error:

```
autoinit.h:143: undefined reference to `__binit__'

autoinit.c:171: undefined reference to `WDTCTL_SYM'

exit.c:68: undefined reference to `__TI_pprof_out_hndl'

exit.c:68: undefined reference to `_symval'
```

I can't find where those are defined.

Comment: 1) Can you provide a link to the bootloader source code ? 
2) You should use the [official GCC toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) provided by Arm for the `Cortex-R/M` devices, and not  `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`, especially if you got it with your Linux distribution.

Comment: are you still there?